# What does **/* mean in maven syntax?

Tags: maven-2

I'm new to maven, I keep running in to the following syntax:

```
<include>**/*</include>
```

Im not sure how to interpret `**/*`, is this some Java or maven convention?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It is more related to [`<fileset>` Ant convention](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) upon which Maven is built.

`**/*` : all files in all subdirectories: see [Ant Patterns](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns).

> When `**` is used as the name of a directory in the pattern, it matches zero or more directories.
>   For example: `/test/**` matches all files/directories under `/test/`, such as `/test/x.java`, or `/test/foo/bar/xyz.html`, but not `/xyz.xml`.

Comment: Is `**/*` the same as `**`? Both mean all files in the directory tree

Comment: Maybe this had changed since my answer 10 years ago.

Comment: Ok, but now is the same or not?

Comment: @Luke Sorry, I was on my phone. No, it is not (for maven at least, as detailed in the answer). It can be the same for other tools (`grep`, for instance, with the bash shell session interpreting `**` differently than maven)

Comment: Can you elaborate the difference between `/test/**` and `/test/**/*`?

Comment: @Luke I don't have much beside the Ant pattern I mention in the answer.

Comment: Ok, as per that answer it's the same then, `/test/**` means any file in any subfolder and `/test/**/*` means the same.

Comment: @Luke Correct, "in any subfolder" indeed. Not in the current folder.